# How to create a virtual column on a gridview based on a particular gridview columns

Tags: vb.net, gridview, linq-to-entities

Please i have a project that i query the database using entity framework as my ORM. This is my query

```
    Dim subjectSearch = From subSearch In DemoSchool.EssenceSubjectRegistrations Where subSearch.Session = drpSession.SelectedItem.Text _
                 AndAlso subSearch.Term = drpTerm.SelectedItem.Text AndAlso subSearch.RealClass.ClassSN = findClassSN.FirstOrDefault AndAlso _
                  subSearch.SubjectCode = drpSubject.SelectedValue _
                  Select New With {.SubjectRegSN = subSearch.SubjectRegSN,
                                  .FirstName = subSearch.Student.FirstName,
                                  .Surname = subSearch.Student.Surname,
                                   .CA1 = subSearch.CA1,
                                    .CA2 = subSearch.CA2,
                                    .CA3 = subSearch.CA3,
                                    .CA4 = subSearch.CA4,
                                    .CA5 = subSearch.CA5}
```

Then i query my result so that i can be able to do some operation on it by doing this

```
    Dim secSubjectSearch = (From jamie In subjectSearch Select jamie).ToList() _
                       .Select(Function(jamie) New With {.SubjectRegSN = jamie.SubjectRegSN,
                       .FirstName = jamie.FirstName,
                       .Surname = jamie.Surname,
                        .CA1 = jamie.CA1,
                         .CA2 = jamie.CA2,
                         .CA3 = jamie.CA3,
                         .CA4 = jamie.CA4,
                         .CA5 = jamie.CA5,
                         .MidTerm = CDbl(jamie.CA1 + jamie.CA2 + jamie.CA3 + jamie.CA4 + jamie.CA5) / 5})
```

The result of the second query is bounded to the gridview which renders properly as it is suppose to rendered. My problem is that i want to create a virtual column called Rank on the gridview after the .MidTerm bounded column that will display the position of each person record in the search result.

```
    NAME        CA1      CA2      CA3    CA4     CA5   MIDTERM    RANK
    James       50        50      60      40      60      52        3
    Essty       100       50      50      50      50      60        2
    Markus      100       40      50      60      50      60        2
    Code        100       100     100     100     50      90        1
```

Above is a format of the gridview columns. I want column Rank to be a virtual column that is calculated based on the Midterm score of the students.Code VB scored 90 so his rank so be 1 and so on.Please i don't know how to calculate this rank column and the code to get the highest and the smallest.Really i need help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways.

1. Use Unbound column and calculate/display the rank
2. Have a RANK field and pre-calculate it and bound it, something like:

   ```
           Dim secSubjectSearch = (From jamie In subjectSearch Select jamie).ToList() _
                  .Select(Function(jamie) New With {.SubjectRegSN = jamie.SubjectRegSN,
                  .FirstName = jamie.FirstName,
                  .Surname = jamie.Surname,
                  .CA1 = jamie.CA1,
                  .CA2 = jamie.CA2,
                  .CA3 = jamie.CA3,
                  .CA4 = jamie.CA4,
                  .CA5 = jamie.CA5,
                  .MidTerm = CDbl(jamie.CA1 + jamie.CA2 + jamie.CA3 + jamie.CA4 + jamie.CA5) / 5,
                  .RANK = -1}).ToList()
           dim sorted = secSubjectSearch.Select(function(n) n.MidTerm).Distinct().OrderByDescending(function(n) n).ToList()
           for each itm in secSubjectSearch
               itm.RANK = sorted.IndexOf(itm.MidTerm) + 1
           next
   ```

-- Not tested, wrote it with notepad...

Comment: worked like a charm. Please can you explain to me why your code worked so that i can learn. Thanks

Comment: Nothing tricky - just store all distinct MidTerm values in a list with descending order, and then for each student, find the correct RANK - by find the index of the MidTerm in the sorted list and then plus one.  of course, we have to have a placeholder for this RANK info: to make it, just put a property RANK with default value of -1 (the value does not matter as you will update it later on)